# how to add a vector layer on top of plotly choropleth_mapbox with raster image?

Tags: mapbox, plotly-python

I am trying to add a vector layer (geopandas) on top of choropleth_mapbox. I can easily make a new choropleth_mapbox figure as follows.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import requests
import plotly_express as px
from shapely.geometry import Point

# import data
data = json.loads(requests.get("http://drive.google.com/uc?id=1ex0kKZgEuhF6-92HyKLW8J1U0r_gxmDM").json())
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(data["features"]).set_geometry("geometry")

# create new choropleth_mapbox
fig=px.choropleth_mapbox( gdf,
                           geojson=gdf.geometry,
                           locations=gdf.index,
                           color="dummy",
                           center={"lon": gdf.iat[0,0].centroid.x, "lat":gdf.iat[0,0].centroid.y},
                           mapbox_style="carto-darkmatter",
                           color_continuous_scale=blues,
                           zoom=13.5
    )
```

and fig.show() displays the figure exactly as expected.
But if I create a figure first:

```
# create figure first
dummy_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame({"geometry":[Point(7.9797197,47.32547143)], "dummy":[1]})

fig=px.choropleth_mapbox( dummy_df,
                           geojson=dummy_df.geometry,
                           locations=dummy_df.index,
                           color="dummy",
                           center={"lon": gdf.iat[0,0].centroid.x, "lat":gdf.iat[0,0].centroid.y},
                           mapbox_style="carto-darkmatter",
                           color_continuous_scale=blues,
                           zoom=13.5
    )
fig.show()
```

and then add the layer as follows:

```
fig.add_choroplethmapbox(geojson=gdf.geometry, locations=gdf.index)
```

I get a TypeError “object of type polygon is not JSON serialisable”

What am I doing wrong?

I have also tried add_trace(go.Choropleth(...)

but this shows empty.

What am I doing wrong? What other way to show a vector map on top of an image on top of a base layer with plotly?